# Print empty line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I am following a beginners tutorial on Python, there is a small exercise where I have to add an extra function call and print a line between verses, this works fine if I print an empty line in between function calls but if I add an empty print line to the end of my `happyBirthday()` I get an indent error, without the added print line all works fine though, any suggestions as to why?

Here is the code:

```
def happyBirthday(person):
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday, dear " + person + ".")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("\n") #error line

happyBirthday('Emily')
happyBirthday('Andre')
happyBirthday('Maria')
```

Comment: You could just say `print("Happy Birthday to you!\n")`

Comment: Post code with your additional print added.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong from a syntax point of view. Maybe you are actually messing up the indent of that last print line in your code. Even your most recent updated code works fine for me.

Comment: A common cause of indent errors is mixing tabs and spaces in your file.  This might be the fault of your editor.  Make sure that all of the lines begin with exactly the same sequence of spaces (and don't use tabs at all).

Comment: ok, I updated it to include it all, @KarthikT thank you as you are correct, it is driving me nuts though as to why it will not work this way though!

Comment: @larsks even if the tab space is 4 and I use 4 regular spaces?

Comment: Yes. A tab is different than 4 spaces.

Comment: works fine on http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/

Comment: Don't use tabs in your Python code!  That way lies madness.

Comment: Well after reformatting it all with the correct indentation and not mixing tabs and spaces all is well, thanks everyone!

Comment: @larsks: I don't agree. I think all that matters is consistency. Some people like tabs for the fact that a tab character is a tab character anywhere, and your editor gets to decide how to display its width but it doesn't influence the code interp.

Comment: @jdi: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends spaces over tabs for good reason.  If you ever share you code with someone else, your use of tabs will cause confusion and errors.  If you never share your code with anybody, I guess it doesn't really matter, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @larsks: I knew the pep-8 comment was to follow :-) It also depends again on their editor if it will cause confusion. My IDE uses the same indent style that is used in the existing file, if I choose to operate that way. I acknowledge that pep-8 is the guide though.

Comment: @larsks I may have not get it correctly, but isn't stupid to press space four times against tab the space once by pressing tab?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will always only get an indent error if there is actually an indent error. Double check that your final line is indented the same was as the other lines -- either with spaces or with tabs. Most likely, some of the lines had spaces (or tabs) and the other line had tabs (or spaces).

Trust in the error message -- if it says something specific, assume it to be true and figure out why.

Comment: "assume it to be true": ne'er a truer word was spake :-)

Answer (score 61):

You can just do

```
print()
```

to get an empty line.

Comment: Comments already identified that this was a tabs vs spaces issue.

Comment: I can say this is more compatible way than `print` or `print()`, since this does the same regardless of the Python version. (If you don't get what I'm saying, try `print()` in _Python 2.x_.)

Answer (score 21):

**Python 2.x:**
Prints a newline

```
print
```

**Python 3.x:** 
You must call the function

```
print()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 6):

Don't do

```
print("\n")
```

on the last line. It will give you 2 empty lines.

Comment: Unless you want to try `print("\n", end = "")`. Don't laugh, I've seen this in the wild :-)

Answer (score 3):

Python's `print` function [adds a newline character to its input](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print). If you give it no input it will just print a newline character

```
print()
```

Will print an empty line. If you want to have an extra line after some text you're printing, you can a newline to your text

```
my_str = "hello world"
print(my_str + "\n")
```

If you're doing this a lot, you can also tell `print` to add 2 newlines instead of just one by changing the `end=` parameter ([by default `end="\n"`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print))

```
print("hello world", end="\n\n")
```

But you probably don't need this last method, the two before are much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This is are other ways of printing empty lines in python

```
# using \n after the string creates an empty line after this string is passed to the the terminal.
print("We need to put about", average_passengers_per_car, "in each car. \n") 
print("\n") #prints 2 empty lines 
print() #prints 1 empty line
```

Answer (score 1):

The two common to print a blank line in Python-

1. The old school way:

   `print "hello\n"`
2. Writing the word print alone would do that:

   `print "hello"`

   `print`

Comment: The code is Python3 in the OP's sample. This won't work.